# C# Soap get Attribute

Tags: c#, vim, soap

I want to parse a answer of a soap request and I want get from the entry `<returnval type="Task">haTask-2-vim.VirtualMachine.powerOn-25</returnval>`
the Value haTask-2-vim.VirtualMachine.powerOn-25 and the Atribute? Task, parsing the value is with innerxml not the problem, but I'm looking to get the Type Task, here is my soap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
 xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<PowerOnVM_TaskResponse xmlns="urn:internalvim25"><returnval type="Task">haTask-2-vim.VirtualMachine.powerOn-25</returnval></PowerOnVM_TaskResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

my code to parse

```
StreamReader objSR = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()); //get the soap from a server
string strResponse = objSR.ReadToEnd();
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(strResponse));
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine( reader.Value);
}
```

my code gives me the following output

```
version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"




haTask-2-vim.VirtualMachine.powerOn-93
```

Comment: show the code how you parse this XML? Generally every xml node has attribute property which can be used to get type

Comment: added now, sorry im realy new in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
StreamReader objSR = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()); //get the soap from a server
string strResponse = objSR.ReadToEnd();
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(strResponse));
while (reader.Read())
{
    if(reader.HasAttributes)
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetAttribute("Type"));
    Console.WriteLine( reader.Value);
}
```

Comment: thank you, works, only confusing thahts looks like PowerOnVM_TaskResponse have the Task Atribute and not my wanted returninterval

Comment: node should be returnval for which type attribute should be read....you must be overlooking something while debugging....

Comment: It will be kind if you accept the answer if it has helped you :)

Comment: ok, mayby someone else still have a idea how i can handle this soap better,

Answer (score 0):

okay I found a "better" Solution, maybe it's crap but working

```
StreamReader objSR = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()); //get the soap from a server
string strResponse = objSR.ReadToEnd();
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(strResponse);
XmlNodeList name = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("returnval");
try
{
    Console.WriteLine(name[0].InnerText + name[0].Attributes[0].InnerText);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch { Exception e; }
```